# Remove all comments from compiled CSS - Grunt

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I have been developing on the front end for years but I am finally making the move towards developing using Grunt and moving away from tools like Prepros and Koala for my Sass compilation.

My main question is, how do I force my grunt tasks to remove all comments from the compiled and minified CSS generated from my SASS files?

Currently I have the following gruntfile.js file snippet setup but this only removes single line comments. I want all of my compiled css to be in one big line with no spacing and no comments:

```
grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     sass: {
       dist:{
           files: {
                'css/main.css' : 'css/main.scss'
           },
           options: {
               style: 'compressed'
           }
       }
     }

})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the "compressed" output option for Sass should already do what you're asking for.

Comment: It doesn't. It keeps all multi-line comments. I basically want to remove library comments that come from things like bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that **grunt-sass** plugin can do this job, but [**grunt-contrib-cssmin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-cssmin) yes.

Set `keepSpecialComments` option  to `0` to remove all comments.

From [cleancss](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-api) documentation :

> keepSpecialComments - `*` for keeping all (default), `1` for keeping first one only, `0` for removing all

Simple example :

```js
cssmin: {
  options: {
      keepSpecialComments: 0 
  },
  target: {
    files: {
      'output.css': ['foo.css', 'bar.css']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the latest version it has been renamed specialComments